# amCharts how to disable tooltip on piechart

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible to completely disable the tooltip on the piechart?

I'm exporting the chart to an image and it sometimes interferes. I'd like a completely static chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to disable pie chart tooltips in v3, set `showBalloon` to false in your makeChart call:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  "showBalloon": false,
  // ...
});
```

In v4, set the series tooltip [`disabled`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#disabled_property) property to true.

```
pieSeries.tooltip.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Perfect! I kept trying tooltips.disabled